# How does Java casting work?

Tags: java, casting

I’m casting a `byte` (8 bits) type into a `short` (16 bits) type, and it seems to me that Java is casting the value of my original var instead of casting the bits.

I solved it by applying a 8 bit mask to the resulting var: `short t = data & 0xFF`.

Does Java cast on the value of the var or on its bits?

Comment: Show an example input output.

Comment: what do you mean by value of var & bits of var? aren't the bits also the value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`byte`, `short` and `int` are all signed (as is long, float and double).  This means when you have a byte of -128 to 127 it remains -128 to 127 in short, int, long, float or double.

If you want to map the range -128 to 127 to 0 to 255 I suggest you use an `int` which is easier to work with in Java.

```
 byte b = -128;
 int i = b & 0xFF; // i == 128
```

As you have 32-bit or 64-bit registers, using a `short` local variable doesn't help you as much as you might think unless you have a lot of them (and I mean millions)  BTW the byte code only allows for two sizes of local variables, one slot (boolean, byte, short, float, int, reference) and two slot (long and double)  Note: reference uses one "slot" even on 64-bit JVMs.

The only unsigned type is char.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the types, but does not long belong to these as well?

Comment: @TwoMore Added the three other signed types)

Answer (score 6):

Java converts the value. The datatype itself is responsible for any bit representations; the value does hypothetically<sup>*</sup> not even need to be a bit pattern under the hood.

<sup>* If you build a computer which does not use bits</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Java treats [some primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) as signed values, to treat the value as unsigned you need to mask the sign bit

Comment: To be pedantic, `boolean`, `char` and `void` are not signed.